# Upload Media Message in Twilio Chat via REST

Tags: twilio, chat, x-www-form-urlencoded

I can upload media/file to Twilio using REST (Python Request), however then Mime-Type is wrong and filename is null. I don't see any support for this in [Twilio Python Module](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python)

Is it possible to upload the file with its filename information and right Mime Type, like VCF?

I followed this [this docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/media#createupload-a-new-media-resource), however there is no clear guidance to insert the filename

Comment: Same here...
The value set as Content-Type seems to be used as content_type of the returned Media instance.
Still not found a way to specify the filename.
Tried so far: setting the Content-Disposition header, as url encoded param.
I am running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing the same situation and got an answer from Twilio Support.

Even if the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/media#createupload-a-new-media-resource) says to set Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, in order to be able to specify a filename, you can post the media like so:

```sh
curl -X "POST" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "media=@/path/to/media.jpg;type=image/jpeg" "https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/<chat_instance_sid>/Media/" -u "<acount_sid>:<account_secret>"
```

Better late than never :)

Comment: Yap, I had informed Twilio to update their docs. :-)